# reducing errors using boolean arrays in C++

Tags: c++, enums, boolean, strong-typing

I'm working on a number of boolean variables that I am now converting into boolean arrays:

```
bool bool_var -> bool bool_var[SIZE]
```

This leads to error prone behavior, since if previously:

```
if (bool_var) { ... }
```

could return both "true" or "false", this same line of code always returns "true", since     "bool_var" is now a pointer to the array. This is quite error-prone, especially if one is duplicating a large number of variables.

**So here's the question:** is there a less error-prone way of doing things?

The solutions I thought could work:

1. Replacing the boolean type with a strongly typed enum (large overhead in C++03).
2. Some compiler directive to trigger a warning (I couldn't find one..).

Any ideas?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `std::vector<bool>` should be handled with care, it is a specialization that has some pitfalls.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Unfortunately - use of std::vector is not allowed for this application.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: yes, it /can/ be a specialization, but none of the possible pitfalls seem to be relevant for his problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use arrays of a fixed size, you should use `std::array`, or `boost::array` if you don't have C++11-support in your compiler. Alternatively you might also consider using `std::bitset`.

Comment: It looks like bitsets are the indeed the way to go, especially on older versions of C++ with minimum available dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `std::array` use that instead of a plain array:

```
#include <array>

std::array<bool,20> test;
bool fail = test;
```

Gives:

```
test.cc:4:13: error: cannot convert 'std::array' to 'bool' in initialization
```

Comment: Why did you make the array of type `int`?

Comment: @BjörnPollex - I was just showing a general example of it not being implicitly convertable to `bool`. I'll change it though.